# How to address excessive white space around links in unescaped ApexPages.Message messages?

Tags: visualforce, css

I am using:

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="false" showDetail="true"/>
```

and creating the detail message using `String.format` with this pattern:

```
'{0} Payment Specification <a href="/{1}">{2}</a> for Date Range <a href="/{3}">{4}</a> ({5} - {6}).
```

But when presented the white space around the links is excessive:

[image]

Using the browser's "Inspect" feature it seems like the white space in the pattern string does not get merged with vertical whitespace that is also added. Removing the white space in the pattern string only helps a bit.

Is there a technique (CSS?) that solves this problem?

Comment: After inspecting the page found that `<style>
.message .messageText a {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font-size: 91%;
    margin: 0px 8px;
}
</style>` is applied to the anchor tag within the message. The spaces were removed when I changed margin to `margin: 0px 0px` and added the style to VF page. Will this help?

Comment: @HemantJain You are right - it does. So changing the pattern to contain `<a style="margin: 0px;" href="/{1}">{2}</a>` fixes it. Please post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anchor tag with page message is styled as below:

```
<style> 
.message .messageText a { 
   color: rgb(51, 51, 51); 
   font-size: 91%; 
   margin: 0px 8px; } 
</style>
```

The value `8px` is adding extra spaces.

You can change the `margin` attribute to `margin: 0px` and add the style to VF page to eliminate the white-spaces.

Or, as you said, adding style directly to pattern would also work `<a style="margin: 0px;" href="/{1}">{2}</a>`